# Have a problem with AWS SNS(No account found for the given parameters)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Hello I'm trying to add phone numbers contact to aws sns tipic using aws-sdk

I finished configurations by adding accessKeyId and secretAccessKey

This is my configuration

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS({accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',region: 'us-east-2'});
```

and how I'm trying to add the number

```
    let params = {
        Protocol: 'SMS', 
        TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789:users',
        Endpoint: '+XXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
    sns.subscribe(params,(err, data)=>{
        if (err) {
           
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
```

But I'm getting this error

```
message: 'No account found for the given parameters',
```

Comment: Just checking... Did you replace `123456789` with your AWS account number?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It worked, thank you so much I forgot to replace `123456789` with my AWS account  number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your case, you provided a 10-digit number as your AWS account number which I think is not correct.

I think you need to provide your real AWS account number (A 12-digit number, such as `12345678901`).

```
 let params ={
...
TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:{your-AWS-account-number}:users',
...
}
```